# Find the centroid bounded by the curves of $y+x=2$, $y^2=x$

Tags: calculus, limits, integration, definite-integrals

Problem Statement:

> Find the centroid of $y+x=2, y^2=x$

I think my main problem is finding the limits of integration. I originally set it at 0 to 1, but that didn't work.

Comment: Is it "find the centroid of the area between," or "find the centroid of the two intersections?"

Comment: @LordSoth between

Comment: Draw a picture.  To calculate the moment about the $y$-axis, you will need to either break up the integral into $2$ parts, $x=0$ to $1$ and then $1$ to $4$, or use an alternate formula for moment that you may have been told about.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a picture.  The points of intersection are at $(1,1)$ and $(4,-2)$.  The integral over the region $R$ between these curves is then

$$\int_R dx dy = \int_0^1 dx \, \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}} dy + \int_1^4 dx \, \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{2-x} dy$$

The centroid $x$ coordinate is

$$\bar{x} = \frac{\displaystyle \int_0^1 dx \, x \, \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}} dy + \int_1^4 dx \, x\, \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{2-x} dy}{\displaystyle \int_0^1 dx \, \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}} dy + \int_1^4 dx \, \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{2-x} dy}$$

The centroid $y$ coordinate is

$$\bar{y} = \frac{\displaystyle \int_0^1 dx  \, \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}} dy\, y + \int_1^4 dx \, \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{2-x} dy \, y}{\displaystyle \int_0^1 dx \, \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}} dy + \int_1^4 dx \, \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{2-x} dy}$$

Upon evaluating the integrals, I get for the centroid

$$(\bar{x},\bar{y}) = \left(\frac{8}{5},-\frac12\right)$$

Comment: A picture of the region in question: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bAQIO.gif

Comment: @anorton: nice picture.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: To find the limits of integration, solve for x in both equations, set the expressions for x equal to each other, and then find the values of y that satisfy this equation.